# Using @Embedded / @Embeddable with Doctrine 2.5 and Unique Constraints

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

> **Doctrine 2.5** allows [`@Embeddable` and `@Embedded`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html) annotations - giving developers the ability to create Entities alongside Value Objects. If you are using composer, as of May 2014, you need to have: `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in your composer.json to use it.

I have a `Server` entity, and I'm trying to map an `IpAddress` value object against this. `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` work great here.

However, I want the `Server` entity to have a `unique` constraint on the `ipAddress` property - which maps to a *value object*. This would work for a normal property, but for embedded ones, I get an exception when trying to update my schema from my entities:

[image: Doctrine SchemaException - @Embeddable @Embedded]

### Server Entity

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use App\Model\Entity\ValueObjects\Server\IpAddress,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Server
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="servers", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_ip_address", columns={"ipAddress"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Model\Repository\ServerRepository")
 */
class Server
{
   /**
    * @var IpAddress
    *
    * @ORM\Embedded(class="App\Model\Entity\ValueObjects\Server\IpAddress")
    */
    private $ipAddress;
}
```

### IpAddress Value Object

```
namespace App\Model\Entity\ValueObjects\Server;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class IpAddress
 *
 * @package App\Model\Entity\ValueObjects\Server
 *
 * @ORM\Embeddable
 */
class IpAddress
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     *  @ORM\Column(name="ip_address", type="string", length=15, nullable=false)
     */
    private $ipAddress;
}
```

I presume I am mapping the classes together correctly. **How can I place a `unique` constraint on an embedded object's property?** I have tried the `.` syntax when defining the columns section of `uniqueConstraints`, but it was a complete guess and naturally failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Jimbo's edit: *Basically, the answer to this is to remove the UniqueConstraints from the Server object, and place unique directly on the value object property.*

Based on your schema output your column name in the index should be ipAddress_ip_address

> @ORM\Table(name="servers",
>   uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_ip_address",
>   columns={"**ipAddress_ip_address**"})})

Alternatively, if the IP address is unique in all tables it's embedded, then you could place the constraint in the IpAddress class.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 *  @ORM\Column(name="ip_address", type="string", length=15, nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
private $ipAddress;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have added this (and changed the column name to ip_address in both places) and still receive the error in the screenshot in my post: `There is no column with name 'ip_address' on table 'servers'`. It's looking for it in the wrong place.

Comment: @Jimbo does the column actually exist when you check the schema?

Comment: The schema does not exist yet, I am attempting to generate it from these mappings via `orm:schema-tool:update` or `create`, which is when I get the error above.

Comment: @Jimbo I would try creating the schema w/o the unique index to see if the embedded column gets created. Maybe the problem is that the embedded object isn't being picked up and not the index definition.

Comment: It's important in this project that future users / developers can run this command and have the database tables created automatically for them. However I removed the constraint and `--dump-sql` generated: `CREATE TABLE servers (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, status TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, ipAddress_ip_address VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_4F8AF5F7C09C0D3D (ipAddress_ip_address), PRIMARY KEY(id));`

Comment: interesting it looks like your column should be named `ipAddress_ip_address` - also it looks like a unique constraint was created?

Comment: it's probably doctrine's naming convention for embedded columns

Comment: Actually, this is interesting. Even though the db column was named "ipAddess_ip_address" by doctrine, when I use the `Repository::findAll()`, the property is actually just called `ipAddress`, containing the `IpAddress` object :-) Basically, the answer to this is to remove the `UniqueConstraints` from the `Server` object, and place unique directly on the  value object property.

Comment: I didn't fully closely read through all comments, but maybe just leaving http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html#column-prefixing here helps...